C# - TextSelection is dimmed
I am maintaining a VSIX and I try to select the word at cursor with the DTE
I have this function so far, and although it does select the word at cursor, the selection is dimmed. I mean it does not look like a mouse selection, you can barely see it
I expect the selection to be like "done with the mouse" and not dimmed down
  public static void SelectWordAtCursor()
  {
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ThreadHelper.ThrowIfNotOnUIThread();

    Document doc = Distributor.m_dte.ActiveDocument;
    if (doc == null)
        throw new Exception("No open document found");

    TextSelection selection = (TextSelection)doc.Selection;
    if (selection == null)
        throw new Exception("No selection found");

    // Move the cursor to the beginning of the word
    selection.WordLeft();
    int startOffset = selection.AnchorPoint.AbsoluteCharOffset;

    // Move the cursor to the end of the word
    selection.WordRight();
    int endOffset = selection.ActivePoint.AbsoluteCharOffset;

    // Set the selection to the word
    selection.MoveToAbsoluteOffset(startOffset);
    selection.MoveToAbsoluteOffset(endOffset,true);
  }

This is selected by the code above

This is selected with the mouse

Thanks for your help on this

Could this be a focus-related issue? Perhaps the window where the selected text is, needs to be set as Active or something similar?

no it is code issue, I have another function that uses MoveToLineAndOffset instead and selection appears correctly. But here I dont have any line/begin char/end char so I use wordleft/right
